# Adding objects in Multidimensional NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm quite confused on how to add objects in multidimensional arrays.

Is initializing multidimensional arrays are the same with just a simple array?

This is my initialization.

```
testList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I need to do something like

```
testList[i][j] = item;
```

i tried

```
[[[testList objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] addObject:item];
```

but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: you should add more `NSMutableArray` (or `NSArray`) objects to your original `testList`, because **there is no multi dimension array** in objective-c; you could use the `NSMutableDictionary` (or `NSDictionary`) with KVC; or you could combined them with each other; or you could use `NSMutableSet` (or `NSSet`) or you could combine everything with everything... everything is highly limitless, it depends on what kind of data you'd like to represent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are add to much C to do this. This is important to know how to NSMutableArray works and how it's different compare to 2D arrays known from C/C++.

In mutable array you could store another arrays. For example:

```
NSMutableArray *first = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *second = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[first addObject:second];
```

Now you have array in first row in first array! This is something very like C/C++ 2D arrays.

So if you want to add some object to *"0,0"* you do this:

```
NSString *mytest = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
[second addObject:mytest];
[first addObject:second];
```

So now your *second* contains *NSStrings* and *first* contains *second*. **Now you can loop this like you want.**

***----EDIT:***
IF you want 1,0 you simply need another instance of *second* NSMutableArray. For example you have this array:

[image: arr]

So here you will be have 3 elements in *second* array.

```
NSMutableArray *first = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i =0 ; i < your_size_condition ; i++) {//if you have size, if don't not a problem, you could use while!
   NSArray *second = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:"@something",@"somethingelse",@"more",nil];
   [first addObject:second];
}
```

You may want to implement [NSCopying protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to do this.

Comment: hmm, i think i got what you mean, but then what if i want to add at 1,0?

Answer (score 4):

If you need a fixed size array, then use plain C array. Before using dynamic ObjC array it needs to create it:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:N];
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:M]];
}
```

UPD: The following methods might be helpful to work with such array:

```
[[array objectAtIndex:i] addObject:obj];
[[array objectAtIndex:i] insertObject:obj atIndex:j];
[[array objectAtIndex:i] replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:obj];
```

Comment: nope, the sizes are dynamic, i just need to know how to add objects in something like testList[i][n]

Comment: in NSMutableArray you don't have to declare size first, you simply add another object. There is more like lists in c++ than arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[testList objectAtIndex:i] insertObject:item atIndex:j];
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @onegray's answer, you can set up some category methods to make soft multidimensional arrays easier to deal with.

MultiMutableArray.h

```
@interface NSMutableArray(MultiMutableArray)
  -(id)objectAtIndex:(int)i subIndex:(int)s;
  -(void)addObject:(id)o toIndex:(int)i;
@end


@implementation NSMutableArray(MultiMutableArray)
```

MultiMutableArray.m

```
#import "MultiMutableArray.h"

-(id)objectAtIndex:(int)i subIndex:(int)s
{
    id subArray = [self objectAtIndex:i];
    return [subArray isKindOfClass:NSArray.class] ? [subArray objectAtIndex:s] : nil;
}

-(void)addObject:(id)o toIndex:(int)i
{
    while(self.count <= i)
        [self addObject:NSMutableArray.new];
    NSMutableArray* subArray = [self objectAtIndex:i];
    [subArray addObject: o];
}

@end
```

example, MultiArrayTests.m

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

#import "MultiMutableArray.h"

@interface MultiArrayTests : SenTestCase
@end

@implementation MultiArrayTests

-(void)testMultiArray
{
    NSMutableArray* a = NSMutableArray.new;
    [a addObject:@"0a" toIndex:0];
    [a addObject:@"0b" toIndex:0];
    [a addObject:@"0c" toIndex:0];
    [a addObject:@"1a" toIndex:1];
    [a addObject:@"1b" toIndex:1];
    [a addObject:@"2a" toIndex:2];
    STAssertEquals(a.count, 3U, nil);
    NSMutableArray* a1 = [a objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray* a2 = [a objectAtIndex:1];
    NSMutableArray* a3 = [a objectAtIndex:2];
    STAssertEquals(a1.count, 3U, nil);
    STAssertEquals(a2.count, 2U, nil);
    STAssertEquals(a3.count, 1U, nil);
}

@end
```

I have written further details at http://peterdeweese.tumblr.com/post/27411932460/soft-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-objective-c